# Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() and Context.User.Identity.Name are returning null in Hub in signalR

Tags: signalr, asp.net-identity, signalr-hub, signalr.client, http-token-authentication

Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() and Context.User.Identity.Name are returning null in AppHub.cs (Hub) in signalR. In this I am using Token based authentication in Identity Framework.

Comment: Seems like an authentication issue, not a SignalR issue. Are you logged in?

Comment: yes.. logged in with tokens... and for signalR passing that token using Query string. Other than query string is there any way to pass token ??